# How to compare two of array in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tow of array like this example

```
array1=['3','1','2','5'];

array2=['1,2,3,4,5','1,2,3,5,6,7','1,4,5,6,7'];
```

i try this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (var j= 0; j< array2.length; j++) {
      if()
      --------
    }
}
```

i want to compare these two of array1 and array2 if all elements of array1 is in array two will display element of array2 that match with array compare (array1) and display true and false.

Comment: `array2` is not array of arrays, it is array of strings..

Comment: We don't work with `Urgent please help!!` here.

Comment: how can we compare??

Comment: @Rayon how can we compare this??

Comment: @JaromandaX how can we compare this??

Comment: compare what? you haven't explained your problem very well ... what is your input (you've shown that) - what is your expected result - you haven't shown that ... `will display` - where? on the web page? in the console? on a billboard? in the sky?

Comment: @JaromandaX i want to show true or false if all elements in array1 match with element of array2

Comment: which is it? true or false? can you add *to the question* the expected output - looking at the arrays, you have one array of `'3', '1', '2', '5'` - the elements of array2 are `'1,2,3,4,5','1,2,3,5,6,7','1,4,5,6,7'` - just by looking at them, there is no **element** in `array2` that matches any (let alone ALL) elements of `array1` - e.g. the STRING "1,2,3,4,5" does not match any of "3" or "1" or "2" or "5" - you can see, they are different strings, right?

Comment: @JaromandaX output it by  console.log i need only result array1 match with array2 will console.log display true

Comment: you keep saying that without actually adding to the question the actual expected output/result - you know what you want the result to be, we don't - - enlighten us

Comment: @JaromandaX my script:   var array1=['3','1','2','5'];
                var array2=['1,2,3,4,5','1,2,3,5,6,7','1,4,5,6,7'];
                var arr = array1.join(',');
                var res = array2.filter(function (a) {
                    return a.includes(arr)
                })
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.length > 0)

Comment: `var result = array2.map(i => i.split(',')).filter((arr, index) => array1.every(v => arr.includes(v))).map(arr=>arr.join(','));`

Comment: ['3','1','2','5'] is in ['1,2,3,4,5'] but it still return false.

Comment: @JaromandaX i got error with this sign =>

Comment: you'll need to transpile it [babel is a good choice](http://babeljs.io/repl/), or **not use internet exploder**

Comment: @JaromandaX i already use it but i still got error with log Uncaught ReferenceError: res is not defined

Comment: `i already use it` - another informative sentence ... WHAT do you already use? and if `res is not defined` that's hardly anything to do with the code I posted is it

Comment: @JaromandaX : it's work tank you very much i confuse with var result not var res

Comment: I've posted this as an answer, along with workarounds for using Internet Exploder 9 or later ... 8 or earlier, you'll need to provide a polyfill for `Array#map`, `Array#every`, `Array#filter` - along with `Array#includes` (which I put in the answer already)

Comment: @JaromandaX : Really thank for your time try to understand my question i am new for stackoverflow

Comment: it's all good @Rajes

Comment: Presently there seems to be a lot of clarification discussion in the comments, but the question is still unchanged. The question itself needs to contain an understandable version of the question. I'm voting to put this on hold now, but I would like it to remain open (or be reopened). Rajes, do still edit it - please don't refrain from improving it just because you've got your answer. Let's make it useful for future readers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the result to be the strings in Array2 that have (at least) all the digits in array1

```
var result = array2.map(i => i.split(',')).filter((arr, index) => array1.every(v => arr.includes(v))).map(arr=>arr.join(','));
```

.map - splits the strings of array2 to separate digits

.filter - applies a filter to the resulting array

.every - checks that every value in array1 exists in the current array2 item

.map - used to map the "split" array back to the original string

.join - joins the arrays back to the original string value in array2

If you're using Internet exploder, you'll need to transpile the code because Internet Exploder is old - here is the result of transpiling

```
var result = array2.map(function (i) {
    return i.split(',');
}).filter(function (arr, index) {
    return array1.every(function (v) {
        return arr.includes(v);
    });
}).map(function (arr) {
    return arr.join(',');
});
```

that leaves only the possibility that in IE, arrays do not have the `every` and `includes` methods. IE9+ has `every`, but `includes` is not supported in IE at all

simple dodgy polyfill for Array#includes for Internet Exploder

```
Array.prototype.includes = Array.prototype.includes || function(v) {
    return !!~(this.indexOf(v));
};
```